# overload operator+ only for specific case of the class

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I have a `class matrix` where I want to overload the `+` operator but only if both matrices have the same number of rows and columns.

```
class matrix
{
private:
    int rows, columns;
    double* data;
public:
    //things here: constructor, destructor etc.
    matrix operator+ (const matrix&) const;
};
```

Then I only want to add two matrices if they have the same number of rows and columns.
What I am doing now is:

```
matrix matrix::operator+(const matrix& adder) const
{
if(rows == adder.rows() && columns == adder.columns())
{
    matrix temporal;
    //Perform the addition
    return temporal;
}
else
    std::cout << "Unable to add matrices" << std::endl;
    //return an empty matrix of 0 rows, 0 columns.
}
```

My problem is that I am able to "add" any two matrices this way. Is there any way I can overload the operator only for the case when the matrices are of equal size (and get an error when I try to compile adding two matrices that can not be added)?

I am having the same problem using the parametrized constructor when I only want to create a matrix with positive number of rows and columns. What I do so far is declare the constructor with two integers, and in the case I get wrong integer input just create an empty matrix. This causes the same problem because I am allowed to "create" a matrix with negative rows, but I dont find out until I want to use the matrix later.

Comment: How would the compiler know how many rows and columns a matrix has at runtime?

Comment: When you are in a state, when you can't do anything useful, and the fact, that you are there is an error, why not just, you know, throw an exception?

Comment: There's no compile time detection of the number of rows and columns (which could be caught with `std::enable_if`). If you want to prevent that situation, you should throw an exception,, or at least an assertion, since your implementation isn't capable of different values of rows and columns.

Comment: Since `matrix` has no compile-time concept of size, it's impossible to enforce restrictions based on size at compile time. You will need to handle this at run time or drastically change how `matrix` is implemented to include compile-time size information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can overload the operator only for the case when the matrices are of equal size (and get an error when I try to compile adding two matrices that can not be added)?

A compile time error cannot be generated for a runtime error.

You can generate a compile time error if you are willing to make the dimenstions of the matrix known at compile time. This can be achieved using

```
template <size_t NUM_ROWS, size_t NUM_COLUMNS>
class matrix
{
   ...
};
```

You'll have to figure out whether that would need your requirements.